# How to store location in Firebase in real-time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, geolocation

I am using Android Studio with Firebase. I have linked my project to database and completed the user interface for sign in and sign up. The users are now able to sign up and I can see that in the Firebase. Once the user signs in, they can see the MapsActivity (the google map where they can track their own location but this location is not stored anywhere, I watched a YouTube tutorial about tracking your own location)

Problem: What I really want is that when the user signs up, their location is also sent to the database (so each user has an attribute called the location) so that when the user logs in, his/her own location can be retrieved for tracking the location.

Basically, Firebase should store the location upon user sign up and keep updating it as the user moves. Once the user logs in, the location should be retrieved (so that the user can track the current location). Again, so when the user is moving, the location in the Firebase should be updated.

I tried looking up online but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html). Here's a simple example :

```
 LocationListener locationListener = new android.location.LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            // Push your location to FireBase
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };
```

Then you pass your **locationListener** to the LocationManager

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

This will listen both from the GPRS and NetworkProvider for location change

To push the changes to the Firebase you can do in the following way

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
```

When posting to the database you have to uniquely identify a row, just like in normal database (i.e ID, UUID), so you'll have to generate one and store into you `SharedPreferences` for example.

```
public void postToDatabase(UserLocation location) {
    DatabaseReference usersRef = myRef.child(someUUID);
    usersRef.setValue(location);
}
```

To listen for changes you have to implement a `ValueEventListener`. An example, but will have to adapt to it your needs

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserLocation location = new UserLocation();
                location.setLongitude((String) snapshot.child("longitude").getValue());
                location.setLatitude((String) snapshot.child("latitute").getValue());
               //Dispatch your changes in application, i.e with and EventBus
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: That's what I am doing currently. And I can track my own location. But I want to store the location of each user in the database and retrieve that...

Comment: So as I understand, the problem you have is to push your location to the Firebase real-time database and check for changes ? Did you implement the ``ValueEventListener`` from Firebase that listens to the database changes ?

Comment: My problem is how to store the location to the Database?

Comment: Edited the answer, you can look now, but I think you can find plenty of resources on the internet about this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this and get back to you! :)